# Random choice selections are made with equal probability

Tags: python, random

I have a questions about random.choice of Python
I choose list have 8 elements. When I choice 120 millions, selections are not made with equal probability.

Example: Number 1: 8M choiced, 2: 15M choiced.

When I read docs function

```
      If the relative weights or cumulative weights are not specified,
        the selections are made with equal probability.
```

Who can explain for me this trouble?

Python3.6

```
list_queues = ["{}_{}".format(queue_name, random.randint(1, I)) for I in range(1, 8)]
```

Comment: `list_queues = ["{}_{}".format(queue_name, random.randint(1, i)) 
for i in range(1, 8)]` gives you already a bias towards lower numbers. (first entry has to be 1, second entry has a 50% chance to be 1, third a 33% chance ...) so 1 should make up 32.4% of your data just after that.

Comment: you might want to change `["{}_{}".format(queue_name, random.randint(1, i)) for i in range(1, 8)]` to `["{}_{}".format(queue_name, random.randint(1, 7)) for i in range(1, 8)]`